# Preventing MySQL from inserting implicit default values into not null columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to use multiple inserts (in one statement) and I have this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE Scores
(
  studentID varchar(50) not null,
  score int
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

My Query:

```
INSERT INTO Scores Values
('Barry', 45),
(NULL, 41),
('Jones', 53)
```

This statement (I expected) should fail since [StudentID] column does not accept NULL.
The problem was MySQL inserted empty string ('') into row 2... and allow the rest to continue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue:

```
SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

or put

```
SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
```

under `[mysqld]` into `my.cnf` (then restart `MySQL`).

Comment: what if i don't have that privilege on MySQL?? Is it possible to do that from my PHP? And also, MySQL documentation says changing SQL_MODE could affect other parts of the DB (e.g. Partition, Master+Slave...)

Comment: @tunmisefasipe: all users have that privilege (for their current session). To do it from `PHP`, just issue `mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES'")` or its analog in the library you're using. Yes, it can affect other parts of the database.

Comment: Thanks @Quassnoi I'll try this out and see how things goes